# Stopping 21 bitcoin computer miner

Tags: 21-bitcoin-computer

So I've read [this article](https://21.co/learn/introduction-to-the-21-bitcoin-computer/#step-1-mine-some-bitcoin) about how to start mining, and I've started mining, now how do I stop mining? the article seemed to neglected that part..

Comment: Unplug the power? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no *21* command for that. You need to: `sudo minerd --stop`